# Swift - Different push animation in Xcode 11.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Something weird is happening with my `push`-transition to another `ViewController`. I changed nothing on that code since yesterday but somehow there are two different `push` animations now.

Here is my code:

```
if methods == nil {

    self.logoStackView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    let SignUpView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpVC") as! SignUpViewController

    SignUpView.email = self.email

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SignUpView, animated: false)

}
//Email ist registriert -> login
else {

    self.logoStackView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    let LoginView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginViewController

    LoginView.email = self.email

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginView, animated: false)
}
```

The animation is working just like before if transitioning to "SignUpVC". However if it transitions to "LoginVC" it animates from the top right corner. 
Is there anything new in Xcode 11.3?

[Screenvideo showing the animation](https://workupload.com/file/NQ5cZy5C)

Comment: Can you create a small downloadable demo project?

Comment: Here is my git: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

Comment: @matt I updated my question with a video of the transition

Comment: Remove those `UIView.animate` which is animating self.view's layout.. It might be happening at the same time and cancelling the push animation. See if it helps

Comment: nope. That's not it. The weird thing is that the other transitions which is pretty much the exact same code works perfectly fine

Comment: I just checked.. You have quite a lot of ambiguous or missing constraints. I have never seen a project constrained like this. You hard coded the width of the stack-view in `SignUp`.. You actually hardcoded the width and height of every control: https://imgur.com/a/RhNjA3f and on different devices (any device that is not the same size as iPhone 11 or X), it's literally going to either crash or break or not look like what you want.

Comment: That being said, your problem is the constraints. You need to make sure every single view is fully properly constrained. Also why not use the storyboard push? You can drag an outlet from the button to the other controller to have it push that controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204448/discussion-between-chris-and-brandon).

Comment: This was golden, thank you for bringing cheer to my day.

Comment: haha :D ur welcome